# Accessing private instances of Github and Gitlab through their respective Python APIs

Tags: git, github, gitlab, pygithub, python-gitlab

Can I access private instances of Github and Gitlab through API wrappers in python such as pygithub and python-gitlab. For example, if I want to access my company's private server of Github and Gitlab, is it possible? Any help on the matter would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using python-gitlab, use:

```
import gitlab
gl = gitlab.Gitlab('http://your_gitlab_instance_url.com', private_token='token')
```

Mentioning the url of the private instance does the job. The method may fail though, if there is some other secondary forms of security authenticators.

When using pygithub, use:

```
from github import Github
g = Github(base_url="https://{hostname}/api/v3", login_or_token="access_token")
```

Works fine with the Rest API for github api v3